# Reputation Fluctuation?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

So today I was awarded upwards of 200 points from previous posts within about an hour, so I figured glitch. And sure enough, points were removed. Anyone know what the heck is going on?

Comment: Someone went on a (up)voting rampage on your posts.  It was caught by the vote fraud scripts and removed.  End of story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like someone went vote-happy on you and the votes got cleared out by the voting fraud detection script.

It's unfortunate when that happens for legitimate upvotes, but it also serves a valuable purpose of removing similarly cast downvotes or upvotes cast to artificially inflate someone's reputation.

Comment: Ahhh never knew such a scenario was even possible. Thanks.